# How to have a reference to an object of some class inside that class

Tags: c#

I've got a problem. Let's say I've got a class Node

```
    public class Node 
    {
        int nevermind_variable;

        Node[] neighbours;
    }
```

So, in my project I really need class `Node` having attributes of `Node`. Of course I know that the code above won't work, but I have no idea, how to implement `Node` objects's neighbours (I must have references), which are `Node` type too...

**EDIT:**
In my project, Node instance is a cell having some physical properties used for further calculations in 2D grid. I've got there Moor and von Neumann neighbourhood. Actually, the code still hasn't work and I got StackOverflowException. Creating 'node1' leads to creating its 8 neighbours, and every of them has 8 neighbours... and so on, so I guess that was a cause of my code not working. 
I worked it through by creating base class for Node (lets say 'NodeBase'), copied there all attributes form Node without neighbours[] and its assignment loop (this prevents making unnecessary neighbours endlessly), making Node inherits from NodeBase (and having all neighbours array things like originally), and changing a type of neighbours array to NodeBase. A little confused, but maybe this would help someone else.

Comment: `I know that the code above won't work`  Why won't that code work?  Looks perfectly valid so far.

Comment: A class can totally reference itself!

Comment: What do you mean it can't work? It's very standard for a `Node` class to have a `Node` property (which is what I assume you're referring to when you say "attribute"). Often it there will be `Node Next` and `Node Previous` properties, or `Node Right` and `Node Left` properties. `List<Node> Neighbors` is also just fine.

Comment: Got a StackOverflowException though...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. The code, as is, looks fine. So the bug must be in some code that you aren't showing to us.

Comment: It looks like OPs question is about designing (and initializing) something like an 8-way-linked list, so to understand the problem we need to see the part of the code that creates and links instances of the `Node` class. There is no technical issue referencing a class from its attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine so far. Each `Node` can have an array of itself as `Node[]` neighbours.

An alternative approach is to have an encapsulating class such as `NodeInfo` if you feel like it's easier to reason about things in this (non-self-referencing) format:

```
public class NodeInfo
{
    public Node Current {get; set;}
    public Node[] Neighbours {get; set;}
}
```

You could also limit the neighbours count (such as in a 2D array) to, for example, 2 by using Left and Right properties:

```
public class Node 
{
    int nevermind_variable;

    Node left; // Could also be called previous, for example
    Node right; // Could also be called next, for example
}
```

Same difference for the most part, and just depends on your preferred approach.

Comment: (`previous`, `next`) => `ListNode` & (`right`, `left`) => `TreeNode` is a common approach.